# I want to display data from database.if we newly add a form data ,i want to append the new post on display without refresh using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I have a show and hide div. That is an add form. I want to display all data from the table on the bottom of the form. If form is opened or not, the data must be displayed. When we add new post, that must append on the top of displayed data without refresh.

**My view**

```
    <div class="slidingDiv" style="display:none">


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="box box-primary">
                                <div class="box-header">
                                    <h3 class="box-title">Add Requirement Item</h3>

                                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                <!-- form start -->
                               <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                               <?php 
                               $attributes = array('id' => 'myForm');
                               echo form_open_multipart(base_url().'moderator/Requirement/add_employee_data',$attributes); ?>
                                    <div class="box-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                            <label for="txttitle">Requirement Title (Product/Service) : </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                            <input type="text" name="txtService" class="form-control" id="txttitle" placeholder="Requirement Title (Product/Service) : " value="" required>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div> 
                                            </diV>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                                                            <label for="txtquantity">Estimated Quantity : </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                            <label for="txtquantity"></label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                                                            <input type="text" name="txtQuantity" class="form-control" id="txtquantity" placeholder="Estimated Quantity" value="
                                                                   " required>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                          <select class="form-control" name="txtunit" required="required">
                                        <option value="">----Select------</option>
                                        <?php
                                        foreach ($units as $name) {
                                            echo ' <option value="' . $name->id . '">' . $name->name . '</option>';
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div> 
                                            </diV>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                            <label for="txtdetails">Requirement Details : </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                            <textarea class="textarea" name="txtRequirement" placeholder="Requirement Details" id="txtdetails" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;">
                                                        </textarea>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                            <label for="sbUser">Expiry of Requirement : </label><br>
                                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <input id="thedate" type="text" name="txtBidclosing" class="form-control"  required="required"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                    <div class="box-footer">
                                   <input type="button" class="button" value="submit" />
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
  <div  id="sort">
<br>
 </div>
```

**Ajax code**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".button").click(function(){
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/Requirement/add_employee_data",
data:$("#myForm").serialize(),
success: function (dataCheck) {
//alert(dataCheck);
$('#sort').append(dataCheck);
//window.location.reload();},
});});});
</script>
```

**Model**

```
public function add_employee_data($data){
$this->db->insert('jil_requirementdetail',$data);
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('jil_requirementdetail');
$this->db->where('rqmd_id',$id);
$result = $this->db->get()->result();
return $result;
}
```

Comment: Where is the html for items list?

Comment: but you get my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On your model**

```
public function add_employee_data($data){
    $this->db->insert('jil_requirementdetail',$data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('jil_requirementdetail');
    // $this->db->where('rqmd_id',$id); // get all data 
    $this->db->order_by('rqmd_id','DESC');
    $result = $this->db->get();
    if($result->num_row() > 0)
    {
        echo json_encode(['status'=>'pass','data'=>$result->result()];
    }else{
           echo json_encode(['status'=>'fail']);
         }
 }
```

On Ajax Success

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/Requirement/add_employee_data",
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        success: function(dataCheck){
          //alert(dataCheck);
          var res = JSON.parse(dataCheck);
          if(res.status=='pass')
          {
              var user_data = res.data;
              var html = '';
              var length = user_data.length;
              for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
              {
                //your html
                html += '<div>' + user_data[i].name + '</div>'; //add your html structure as you want
              }
              $('#sort').append(html);
            },
       }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: in that html portion, user_data.name,is that name is database field?

Comment: name is database field name

Comment: ,when clicking on the button nothing happend

Comment: on click of button what should be happen?

Comment: on clicking on the button the data shld be inserted to database and that new data should display on top of the display

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
 

var res = JSON.parse(dataCheck);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106326/discussion-between-vinie-and-angel).

Comment: i want the data below every time. not only on the button click